# When is it better to flatten out data using comma separated values to improve search query performance?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-performance, query-performance

My question about SEARCH query performance.

I've flattened out data into a read-only Person table (MySQL) that exists purely for search.  The table has about 20 columns of data (mostly limited text values, dates and booleans and a few  columns containing unlimited text).

```
Person
=============================================================
id      First   Last    DOB         etc (20+ columns)...
1       John    Doe     05/02/1969
2       Sara    Jones   04/02/1982
3       Dave    Moore   10/11/1984
```

Another two tables support the relationship between Person and Activity.

```
Activity
===================================
id      activity
1       hiking
2       skiing
3       snowboarding
4       bird watching
5       etc...

PersonActivity 
===================================
id      PersonId        ActivityId
1       2           1
2       2           3
3       2           10
4       2           16
5       2           34
6       2           37
7       2           38
8       etc…
```

Search considerations:

1. Person table has potentially 200-300k+ rows
2. Each person potentially has 50+ activities
3. Search may include Activity filter (e.g., select persons with one and/or more activities)
4. Returned results are displayed with person details and activities as bulleted list

If the Person table is used only for search, I'm wondering if I should add the activities as comma separated values to the Person table instead of joining to the Activity and PersonActivity tables:

```
Person
===========================================================================
id     First    Last    DOB         Activity    
2      Sara     Jones   04/02/1982  hiking, snowboarding, golf, etc.
```

Given the search considerations above, would this help or hurt search performance?
Thanks for the input.

Comment: And how will you select data? SELECT .. WHERE Activity like '%golf%'? It is really bad idea.

Comment: Really bad idea. Make sure that you have indexes on the `PersonID` and `ActivityID` in the `PersonActivity` table and that you have PK's identified on the `Person` and `Activity` tables.

Comment: Thanks for the help... that's exactly  what I've done with the indexes.

Comment: Typically denormalization for the sake of performance doesn't involve comma-delimiters, but rather repeating values. Imagine you had a join between the one and the many tables (person -> activities); in a denormalized view these tables would be combined into one, with the person repeated as many times as he had linked activities; but there would be only one activity per person per row in this denormalized relation.

Answer (score 3):

Horrible idea. You will lose the ability to use indexes in querying. Do not under any circumstances store data in a comma delimited list if you ever want to search on that column. Realtional database are designed to have good performance with tables joined together. Your database is relatively small and should have no performance issues at all if you index properly.

You may still want to display the results in a comma delimted fashion. I think MYSQL has a function called GROUP_CONCAT for that.